telegraf не отображается inlineKeyboard в сообщении
Пишу бота, и хочу сделать проверку по подписке на канал. Остальные инлайн кнопки отображаются, но здесь нет:
if (isSubscribed) {
    ctx.reply(
        `......`,
        ])
    )
} else {
    ctx.reply(
        `Приветствую @${username}! Чтобы использовать бота, сначала подпишитесь <a href="${channelLink}"> на наш канал</a>. После подписки нажмите на кнопку ниже, чтобы подтвердить подписку.`,
        {
            reply_markup: Markup.inlineKeyboard([
                Markup.button.callback('Я подписался', 'check_subscription'),
            ]),
            parse_mode: 'HTML',
        }
    )
}

далее написан обработчик нажатия на кнопку. Но кнопка не отображается, так что писать для краткости не буду

